# Eliminating the space on the UINavigationBar between the left of the bar and the leftBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I currently have a button image for the leftBarButton of the UINavigationBar.  Is there a way to eliminate the space between this button and the left edge of the UINavigationBar?  I thought about just making a custom image for the background of the UINavigationBar, but I want to be able to use the back buttons that are generated on other screens.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The layout logic of the navigation bar itself is going to want to try to maintain that space on the left side.

You could try specifying a custom view when setting the navigation items  (UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:), and pass in a view with a negative x origin -- but I assume the navigation bar would ignore any such origin.  (You could also try to keep a reference to that view, and move it to the left after the navigation bar finishes its layout)

Another option would be to try to create your own custom navigation bar -- possibly by putting a custom view in the center of the navigation bar, and stretching it to cover the width & height of the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

```
CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
frame.origin.x = -10;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = frame;
```

Basically, set the navigation bar x coordinate to negative not the bar item.

Answer (score 0):

in ios7 you can just add a dummy barbuttonitem
for fixing left space you should add dummy as first, for right as last

example for left, you should add this after setting your original items or in viewdidload if you are setting buttons using storyboard.

```
NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *spacerItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[buttons addObject:spacerItem];
for(UIBarButtonItem *item in self.leftBarButtonItems){
    [buttons addObject:item];
}
[self setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithArray:buttons] animated:NO];
```